# Encrypting Nodes within XML Document in Python

Tags: python, xml, encryption

Is there any library in Python that allows you to encrypt nodes within an xml document without having to encrypt the entire xml document itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more than one tool for this job.

To read an XML file and produce a tree of nodes, I recommend python's [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) API. It's built-in and easy to use.

Walk the tree and find the text you want to encrypt. The [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) library can help you there. Pick a cipher that suits your requirements, or AES if you're not sure. Google found [this example](https://gist.github.com/sekondus/4322469), copied below:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

# the block size for the cipher object; must be 16, 24, or 32 for AES
BLOCK_SIZE = 32

# the character used for padding--with a block cipher such as AES, the value
# you encrypt must be a multiple of BLOCK_SIZE in length.  This character is
# used to ensure that your value is always a multiple of BLOCK_SIZE
PADDING = '{'

# one-liner to sufficiently pad the text to be encrypted
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

# one-liners to encrypt/encode and decrypt/decode a string
# encrypt with AES, encode with base64
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

# generate a random secret key
secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

# create a cipher object using the random secret
cipher = AES.new(secret)

# encode a string
encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, 'password')
print 'Encrypted string:', encoded

# decode the encoded string
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
```

Comment: Thanks. What I intend to do is encrypt based on the tag name of the xml nodes. I have been able to parse the XML files and generate a list of tag names using ElementTree. The challenge is encrypting the tags and still having the files in XML form but with their contents inaccessible until decrytped. A little new to all this so sorry if the question seems silly :)

Comment: You can encrypt the tag names or contents using the technique described above. Attack the problem, and if you need further help, ask another, more specific question. As it is, this one is already answered -- all that remains is some reading, trial and error. You won't get the full code to do it all in this website, by rules and customs. Give it at least half an hour, you'll learn 10x as much :)